# Cant change bootstrap background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, background-image

I have problem with changeing bootstrap 3 background image, as a background of .container i use image, id like to set some other image as background image so it will fill empty space's on sides.

Can i kindly ask for some help ?

[Link to site](http://webconcept.hekko24.pl/bibik3/)

Comment: EDIT: Alerdy tryed use background-image on body with Important and set html background to transparent - no effect .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the image to the body element instead of an element with the class container using css.

```
body {
    background: url('x');
}
```

x can equal an absolute image path or a relative path.

this can also be implemented using inline styling directly on the body element in your html

```
 <body style="background:url('x')">
```

Comment: I made one additional } inside css stylesheet :) my mistake, sorry for trouble